# error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Categories[]>' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the error I get when I try to get all the categories that are listed in my database (Firestore) from my page `sidebar.component.html`

```
 <div class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories">

//error TS2322: Type 'Observable<Categories[]>' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'.
```

Here is my code `sidebar.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/internal/Observable';
import { Categories } from 'src/app/models/categories.model';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  categoriesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Categories>;
  categories: Observable<Categories[]>;
  snapshot: any;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.categoriesCollection = this.afs.collection('categories');
    this.categories = this.categoriesCollection.valueChanges();
    this.snapshot = this.categoriesCollection.snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(
          map(actions => actions.map(a => a.payload.doc.data()))
        )
  }

}
```

The file `categories.model.ts`

```
export interface Categories {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  reference: string
}
```

Can you help me please.
Thanks.

✅ For anyone looking for the answer, here it is :

```
<div class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories | async">
//categories est un observable
```

Answer given by [R. Richards](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5437671/r-richards)

Comment: Try `<div class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories | async">`. `categories` is an observable.